# Probability for cumulative density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, distribution-theory

I have no idea how to do this since I don't have the specific function, and prof says that it's the point in p.d.f. as it is $f(x)$.

This is the problem:

The random variable $x$ is distributed according to the p.d.f. $f(x)$. For two intervals $[F_1, F_2]$ and $[F_3,F_4]$, $0≤F_i≤1$, compute the ratio of probabilities for the cumulative density function $F(x)$ of the function $f(x)$ being in one or the other interval, i.e:
$$R=\frac{\text{Prob}(F_1≤F(x)≤F_2)}{\text{Prob}(F_3≤F(x)≤F_4)}$$

Please Help!!!

Thx!

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE .. please consider using $\LaTeX$or MathJax to format your answer properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f$ and CDF $F$. Solving this problem requires you to work out the distribution of $Y$ if $Y \equiv F(X)$. For simplicity I assume that $F$ is strictly increasing, so that the quantile function $F^{-1}$ is strictly increasing. Then we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y \leq y) &= P\left[ F(X) \leq y \right] = P\left[ F^{-1}\big(F(X) \big)\leq F^{-1}(y) \right]\\
&= P\left[ X \leq F^{-1}(y)\right]\\
&= F\big( F^{-1}(y))= y
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, we see that $Y$ is a Uniform$(0,1)$ random variable. The preceding argument is often called the "Probability Integral Transform." From here we obtain $R = (F_2 - F_1)/ (F_4 - F_3)$.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer! I got the same result, but I thought I should get a number, and I was stuck 'cause I didn't know how to get a number... I hope you're right, because it would mean I knew how to solve it ... :)

Comment: Happy to help. Without knowing the values of $F_1, F_2, F_3$ and $F_4$ there shouldn't be any way to get a specific numerical value. If you found it helpful, it would be great if you could approve my answer. This is the mechanism for indicating that a question has been solved to the original poster's satisfaction on StackExchange sites.